# Docker bridge network curl request

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two docker-compose file.

Firstly upped backend container and inspect the container and copy ip address for extra_hosts for frontend docker-compose file and than upped frontend. But I cant curl port of backend container from frontend container. I get connection time out error. How can I solve the problem?

```
    version: '3'
    
    services:
      frontend:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        image: test/frontend:dev
        container_name: test_frontend_dev_1
        ports:
          - "80:8080"
        extra_hosts:
          - "api-test.local:192.168.144.2"      
        # all below is not necessary in final state
        networks:
          - test_network
        volumes:
          - .:/var/www/html
          - .docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
          - .docker/config/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
        # user: root
        #command: sh
    networks:
      test_network:
        driver: bridge
```

```
    version: '3'
    
    services:
      backend:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        image: test/backend:dev
        container_name: test_backend_dev_1
        ports:
          - "8888:8080"
        expose:
          - 8080
        # all below is not necessary in final state
        volumes:
          - .:/var/www/html
        # user: root
        #command: sh
      db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        restart: always
        environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: 'test'
          # So you don't have to use root, but you can if you like
          MYSQL_USER: 'user'
          # You can use whatever password you like
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'root'
          # Password for root access
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
        ports:
          # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
          - '3306:3306'
        expose:
          # Opens port 3306 on the container
          - '3306'
          # Where our data will be persisted
        volumes:
          - my-db:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
          - test_network
    networks:
      test_network:
        driver: bridge
    ## Names our volume
    volumes:
      my-db:
```

Comment: Why do you run them as different compose files? Are you able to curl if you run all services from one compose file? What exact command do you use for testing?

Comment: Solved. I changed two things. Firstly set the network external because otherwise container networks were seperating automatically with a suffix like "test_network_default" and realized backend service's network was not set up.